# Extensive use of pl/sql in newer application

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, programming-languages

Pl/sql indeed extends the power of SQL greatly. But is heavy use of pl sql justified for newer projects? Almost any business logic can be written outside of the database. Emerging back-end technologies are coming with enhanced performance for the same tasks, offering better debugging and maintainability, and having supprt for the transactional boundaries. Even batch tasks can be performed decently, for ex. Spring batch framework.

What I personally think is that still for the triggers and other small procedures, use of pl/sql is fine. But it should not be used heavily like it was used in legacy projects.

So in what situation, should we go for the pl/sql for new project?

Comment: The question is opinion-based. There's no rule of thumb: each task should be solved with the appropriate tool. It depends on too much criteria: supportability, performance, scalability, change management, and of course the reason why you've chosen this exact DBMS for the backend (you've paid for *some* functionality, why you do not want to use it?). Moving data back and forth, serialization and deserialization, transaction state management doesn't come for free especially for very light and short-lived transactions, they may be much faster/lighter to be performed entirely at the database side.

Comment: _"Almost any business logic can be written outside of the database"_   "Can be" does not mean "should be".    "Emerging back-end technologies are coming with enhanced performance for the same tasks,"  I'm sure that's what their marketing flak says.  Personally, I've _never_ seen it work out that way.  Indeed, my experience has been for developers ask me why their 'framework based' solution is performing poorly, and a low-level trace reveals fundamental issues wit the way the 'framework' implements it, and a PL/SQL solution was orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: In the end, your arguments look like trying to justify a pre-conceived notion that is based on a lack of real world experience.  But then, I've been in this business only 40 years . . .

Comment: *"Almost any business logic can be written outside of the database*" - but your data is inside the database, so every external language or framework has to make a database connection, haul the data out, process it, then push it back in again to save it, all without the dependency tracking and instrumentation that's built into PL/SQL. The only downside I see is the industry culture of not taking PL/SQL seriously as a programming language and consequently allowing everything to be written as rambling uppercase spaghetti code, but this has nothing to do with the technology.

Comment: There's clearly been a long trend to move most application logic outside of the database. But you might want to consider bucking that trend when you need optimal performance; it's faster to bring your algorithms to you data than to bring your data to your algorithms. It doesn't matter how fast Spring is because your network is slow. Oracle is trying to become a "converged" or "multimodel" database, and if you're already invested in Oracle tools then it makes sense to at least consider that approach.

Answer (score 2):

This is, of course, opinion-based (can't be different) so what I think doesn't have to fit anyone else.

---

PL/SQL means *Oracle* which means *database*.

If possible, I'm trying to make database do as many things as it can (via constraints and similar) so that I wouldn't have to do it manually.

I like coding in PL/SQL. My front-ends are more or less *dummy* (contain as little code as possible), used to present information to users. Most of *smart* things are kept in the database (packages mostly, rarely standalone procedures or functions). I use triggers if I must.

---

> Almost any business logic can be written outside of the database

Certainly; but that's not what I do, and don't plan to change it.

Comment: I could copy/paste this answer for me. In my job I faced several time the issue, that the framework tears down the over all performance, esp. when your application works with large data sets. I don't think any (platform independent) framework is able to cover **all** the nice features and functions which are provided natively by the back-end database. I am also not a fan of all these frameworks.

Comment: @Littlefoot, is not the pl/sql quite cumbersome/painful when it comes to debugging and maintaining having limited IDE support?

Comment: Yes, if you are used to line-by-line debugging and "edit code and continue" then PL/SQL is limited. But the answer is as usual: Is it worth to lose all the other fancy stuff? Maybe the reason is, old guys like me grow up without such IDE's, that's the reason why we can work without them. But I also enjoy them, if they are available.